# How to generate a sequence of numbers using another sequence in R

Tags: r, data-generation

I am trying to generate two sequences in R where sequence A will be from 0~1 and B will be from 0~(1-A). I tried with the below commands but it didn't work. Any kind suggestions please?

```
A <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
B <- seq(0, (1-A), 0.1)
```

Comment: Because `1-A` is the reverse of A.  How many numbers should there be in B?

Comment: If I can have 11 numbers in A then same like in B

Comment: I'm not following.  Could you add the desired result to your post?

Comment: Is there any reverse function in R to generate B?

Comment: The function `rev` will reverse a vector.  In this case, `rev(A)` is equivalent to `1-A`

Comment: @RichardScriven you are headed for trouble: `(1-A)` is most certainly NOT the same (in general) as  `rev(A)`, and `seq` will not accept a vector for its `to` argument in any case.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I'm aware that in general, they are not the same.  I was simply saying that for this particular problem, if `A <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)`, then `rev(A)` is equal to `1-A`.